# Why Declare Variables Outside of LWC Class

Tags: lightning-web-components, bestpractice

In the salesforce trailhead "Lightning Web Components and Salesforce Data: Use Apex to Work with Data" we have the following code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
import REVENUE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue";
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts";
const COLUMNS = [
  { label: "Account Name", fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" },
  {
    label: "Annual Revenue",
    fieldName: REVENUE_FIELD.fieldApiName,
    type: "currency"
  },
  { label: "Industry", fieldName: INDUSTRY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" }
];
export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
  columns = COLUMNS;
  @wire(getAccounts)
  accounts;
}
```

In this example, and in many others, variables such as `COLUMNS` are established outside of the central class, rather than inside of it. This is then followed up by something line the line `columns = COLUMNS`.

Why is this? Is there a technical reason for it? Is it just a syntax standard? Why isn't the code written more like this:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
import REVENUE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue";
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts";

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
  columns = [
     { label: "Account Name", fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" },
     { label: "Annual Revenue",fieldName: REVENUE_FIELD.fieldApiName,type: "currency" },
     { label: "Industry", fieldName: INDUSTRY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" }
  ];
  @wire(getAccounts)
  accounts;
}
```

Comment: I've often wondered this myself. Does it confer a speed benefit? A binding benefit? (To the attached template). Readability? or is it just new, so we all gotta do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general "rule" is that you put global constants (`const`) outside the class, which is reminiscent of how constants were used in the old days (e.g. the C language). You cannot place a `const` inside a class and outside of any function. The following is illegal:

```
export default class MyClass extends LightningComponent {
  const name = value;
}
```

However, defining a constant outside the class is beneficial, as it reduces the size of your class and makes it easier to read.

In general, your class should look like this:

```
import things from 'places';

const thatAreGlobal;

export default class MyClass extends LightningElement {
  // public properties
  @api variables;
  // public methods
  @api methods;

  // private properties, also @track'ed variables
  classVariables;

  // Wire methods
  @wire(method, params) result;
  
  // First code to run
  constructor() { // if any
  }
  
  handlers() { // if any
    const somevariable = this.someothermethod(); // we can do this, though.
  }

  utilityAndHelpers() { // if any
  }
}
```

This is meant to keep your code organized, similar to how you should structure a Java class, Apex class, C++ file, etc. Keeping things grouped together makes it easier to maintain in the long run, rather than just randomly putting variables, etc, everywhere.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced I like this design pattern, despite it being the correct answer. I don't think it works well with web components, as generally you have just one class + one template + one css file. So what does 'global' actually mean in that context?

Comment: @CasparHarmer "global" is more historical nomenclature, but in modern JS means "anywhere in the file." I agree that for small scripts, the const design is unnecessary, but I find it helpful once you start building larger classes that are thousands of lines long; there comes a point where organization is more beneficial than "shorter." My main argument is to avoid [magic numbers](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic-number.html), but also to allow easier configuration changes to your source (e.g. columns to display).

Comment: @CasparHarmer Mind you, I'm not saying, *one must absolutely do it this way or face the wrath of some nameless programming deity*, but I do speak from 33+ years of experience in a couple dozen different languages. Putting your configuration in its own special, immutable place in the file is an awesome feature to have when you're building large scripts.

Comment: @sfdcfox Here is another reason for moving immutable objects outside the class body. In JavaScript class fields with initial value is a shortcut for creating a property in the constructor and assigning value. This avoids duplicate allocation of the same immutable object: https://jsfiddle.net/haLf16km/1/

Comment: @pmdartus That's an excellent point. Using inline values in a loop of components would balloon memory usage unnecessarily.